# docker restart container failed: "already in use", but there's no more docker image

Tags: list, nginx, docker, containers

I first got my nginx docker image:

```
docker pull nginx
```

Then I started it:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx
```

Then I stopped it:

```
docker stop webserver
```

Then I tried to restart it:

```
$docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/webserver" is already in use by container 036a0bcd196c5b23431dcd9876cac62082063bf62a492145dd8a55141f4dfd74. You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name..
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Well, it's an error. But in fact there's nothing in container list now:

```
docker container list
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Why I restart nginx image failed? How to fix it?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

It is because

- you have used `--name` switch.
- container is stopped and not removed

You find it stopped

```
docker ps -a
```

You can simply start it using below command:

```
docker start webserver
```

**EDIT: Alternatives**
If you want to start the container with below command each time,

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx
```

then use one of the following:

**method 1:** use `--rm` switch i.e., container gets destroyed automatically as soon as it is stopped

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --rm --name webserver nginx
```

**method 2:** remove it explicitly after stopping the container before starting the command that you are currently using.

```
docker stop <container name>
docker rm <container name>
```

Comment: docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint webserver

Comment: --rm is the most useful docker run flag, ever! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

As the error says.

> You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name

This leaves you two options.

- You may delete the container that is using the name "webserver" using the command

  docker rm 036a0bcd196c5b23431dcd9876cac62082063bf62a492145dd8a55141f4dfd74

and retry.

- Or you may use a different name during the run command. This is not recommended, as you no longer need that docker.

It's better to remove the unwanted docker and reuse the name.

Answer (score 1):

While the great answers are correct, they didn't actually solve the problem I was facing.

### How To:

#### Safely automate starting of *named* docker container regardless of its prior state

The solution is to wrap the `docker run` command with an additional check and either do a `run` or a `stop` + `run` (effectively restart with the new image) based on the result.

This achieves both of my goals:

- Avoids the error
- Allows me to periodically update the image (say new build) and restart safely

```
#!/bin/bash
# Adapt the following 3 parameters to your specific case
NAME=myname
IMAGE=myimage
RUN_OPTIONS='-d -p 8080:80'

ContainerID="$(docker ps --filter name="$NAME" -q)"

if [[ ! -z "$ContainerID" ]]; then
    echo "$NAME already running as container $ContainerID: stopping ..."
    docker stop "$ContainerID"
fi
echo "Starting $NAME ..."
exec docker run --rm --name "$NAME" $RUN_OPTIONS "$IMAGE"
```

Now I can run (or stop + start if already running) the `$NAME` docker container in a idempotent way, without worrying about this possible failure.