# Docker says there is already a container with the same name that exists despite there are no containers

Tags: docker, containers

I do `DOCKERADM_ENV=lab docker-compose -f docker-compose-mgmt.yml up -d` since last week to test things and when I want to test something new I remove all the containers with `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`.

But now I can't make my docker-compose because :

> ERROR: for mgmt-mongo  Conflict. The name "/mgmt-mongo" is already in
>   use by container
>   228f13fb40231043d3c532cc1fa40906eb4332722a6a69024fe6b9d0ceab8b40. You
>   have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that
>   name.

But when I do `docker ps -a` there is nothing.

You have an idea from where it could comes ?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi I'll try but I need to wait because it's on a lab machine ^^ I'll come back later to tell you if it worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker restart container failed: "already in use", but there's no more docker image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760216/docker-restart-container-failed-already-in-use-but-theres-no-more-docker-im)

Comment: @Rao maybe it's a bit linked but there is no solution for him so I think I can keep mine open

Comment: @Rao I don't think it is a duplicate to that since `docker ps -a` does not show anything.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi it worked with a restart, you can put an answer because I can't delete question who already has an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of errors are often caused by Docker upgrades without stopping everything like running containers. A reboot will solve most cases.

Answer (score 11):

run this:

`docker rm 228f13fb40231043d3c532cc1fa40906eb4332722a6a69024fe6b9d0ceab8b40`

sounds like you have a an orphaned container or something like that... but Docker was kind enough to give you the id of the container, so you can just remove that container by its id.

Comment: It doesn't work, I have tried it before and I just did it again to give you the result : 
`Error response from daemon: No such container: 228f13fb40231043d3c532cc1fa40906eb4332722a6a69024fe6b9d0ceab8b40`

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by @TatsuyukiIshi works well, but I think is not necessary to restart the machine. For example, in windows you can go to Docker Settings and go to **Reset** option to **Restart Docker**:

[image: Restart docker]

The same should apply for other OSs

Comment: Restarting for me helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be very misleading ... in my case was just a wrong path within the docker configuration (on win)

```
dockerfile: ./pathToFolder/Dockerfile
```